# Mysql multiple table join to get user details

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

**Table - User**

```
userId ||  username ||  profileImage
------------------------------------
1      ||  aa       ||  aaaaa.png

2      ||  bb       ||  bbbb.png

3      ||  cc       ||  cccc.png

4      ||  dd       ||  dddd.png
```

**Table - Relationship**

```
relationshipId  ||  user1  ||  user2 ||  status
-----------------------------------------------
1               ||  1      ||  2    ||  0

2               ||  1      ||  3    ||  1

3               ||  1      ||  4    ||  1

4               ||  2      ||  4    ||  1
```

So I want the details of all the users (3,4) whom 1 has sent request and status is accepted as 1.

Something I tried :

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("
SELECT users.uId
     , users.username
     , users.profilePic 
  from users
  JOIN relationship 
 WHERE (relationship.user_one_Id = :profileUserId || relationship.user_two_Id=:profileUserId) 
   AND relationship.statusCode=:statusCode
   AND users.uId != :profileUserId 
 LIMIT 6
");

$stmt->bindvalue(":statusCode", 1);
$stmt->bindparam(":profileUserId", $profileUserId);
$stmt->execute();
```

But this query is giving me rows including those with whom I am not friends too. So where did I go wrong.

Comment: what is `$profileUserId`?

Comment: its the id of the profile i am viewing.. which my be my own profile r any other user's in the sytsem.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Tell me if my assumption is wrong: given an user ID, you want to retrieve data about every user linked to the former?

Comment: @Reversal the question implies that your assumption is wrong, but the failed query implies that your assumption is spot on, so I've no idea which is right. Also. The column names change, which doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where `relationship.user_one_Id` comes into the picture. I assume you meant to write `relationship.user1`? I also assume that the sender is stored in `user1`. In which case your query is way too complicated:

```
SELECT t.uId, t.username, t.profilePic
FROM users t
INNER JOIN relationship r
    ON (t.id = r.user2
        AND r.user1 = :profileUserId
        AND r.status = :statusCode
    )
```

Comment: yes the user1 is the user id of user who sends request, but that doesnt mean user id of that user can be found in another column i.e user2 column as her might get request too from others and be friend. so that makes the query complex in whole.